# Matching the values of Split string in if condition

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

What I'm trying to achieve is to match the Source doc no. of `PER SAWT` to P`ER MAP`.
If it matches it will automatically check the CheckBox and it will set the `BackColor` to `Color.Yellow`.

But when I try to split the Source Doc in `PER MAP`, it will only get the 2nd Value which is `BS091` as per screenshot in 1st Scenario.

My code work in 2nd scenario.

1st Scenario
[image]

2nd Senario
[image]

Here is the code:

```
For x As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim sdoc_sawt As String = DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No").Value.ToString
    'Sample Value: "RR0022/BS091/BS092/BS093"

    Dim sdoc_map As String = DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No_P").Value.ToString
    Dim split_sdoc As String() = sdoc_map.Split("/")

    Dim part As String
    For Each part In split_sdoc
         If Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No").Value.ToString = part Then

            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells(0) = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell With {.Value = True}

            '-------Will automatically color the yellow of math Source Docu no.----------'
            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("ATC").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Prepaid_Tax").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No_P").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("ATC_P").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Tax_Withheld_P").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            '-----------------------------------End---------------------------------------'
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Do you mean, you want to set as `Checked` a Row of the `PER SAWT` grid if at least one of the Rows in `PER MAP` has a `Source_Doc_No` field that contains a value that matches the `Source_Doc_No` field in `PER SAWT`? If the `Source_Doc_No` field in `PER MAP` of the corresponding Row is null/empty, keep the last valid/non empty value as reference?

Comment: Yes exactly, my Problem is BS092 and BS093 in PER SAWT didnt match, only BS091 matches in per MAP,

my problem is in this Line
If Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No").Value.ToString = part Then

Comment: Your code, as of now, could work (except, `Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells(0) = New DataGridViewCheckBoxCell With {.Value = True}` should be `Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value = True`. You also should set `Option Strict On`, it helps a lot  in writing correct code). Can you show how are you currently retrieving the `Source_Doc_No` field value of `PER MAP`? This value, of course, can't be hard-coded like this: `RR0022/BS091/BS092/BS093 `

Comment: Its same on how i retrieve value in PER SAWT i just added_P -  Dim sdoc_map As String = DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No_P").Value.ToString,, I don't have problem in checking the checkbox, the problem is spliting the value of Souce Doc No. in Per MAP.

Comment: Still not clear. Does the `Source_Doc_No_P` field of `PER MAP` contain a valid value in the **first Row only when some values are missing**, or it can be anywhere else? There might be **more that one valid value**, inter-mixed with null/empty values? In the second grid, all values are set. Describe the frequency of these values. If you don't explain how your data objects are structured and what results you're expecting, it's difficult to suggest something meaningful.

Comment: i did some checking using Msgbox to check the Value of part in the  For Each part In split_sdoc,   If Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No").Value.ToString = part Then
//for testing to show the value in part
Msgbox(part) the result is RR0022 and BS091,  so the only value shows is only 2 i did now show the  BS092 BS093

Comment: The problem is not splitting the string, is splitting a null/empty string when there's not data in the `Source_Doc_No_P` field. If you answer the questions I asked in my previous comment, I can suggest how to proceed. Don't focus on the `Split()` thing, it's irrelevant.