# Split String inside If Condition does not show all split value. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am comparing the splitted `Source_Doc_No_P` of PER MAP to PER SAWT then if it matched it will color the BackColor of DataGridview into yellow but there is something wrong in my code when the split value of `Source_Doc_No_P` is inside the `If` condition it only get 1 value of splitted string. Please see the screen-shot and code to help you understand my problem.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim sdoc_map As String = DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No_P").Value.ToString

    Dim split_sdoc() As String = sdoc_map.Split("/")

    For Each part As String In split_sdoc
        'Output of split_doc after For each loop
        'BS091
        'BS092
        'BS093
         If part = Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No").Value.ToString Then
             'Output of split_doc after If condition
             'BS091
             'It should be
             'BS091
             'BS092
             'BS093A

             '-------Will automatically color the yellow of mathced Source Document----------'
             Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells(0).Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
             Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
             Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("ATC").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
             Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Prepaid_Tax").Style.BackColor = Yellow

             Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No_P").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
             Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("ATC_P").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
             Me.DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Tax_Withheld_P").Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            '-----------------------------------End---------------------------------------'

            End If
        Next
Next
```

Current Result
[image: img1]

What should be the result
[image: img2]

Comment: `Source_Doc_No_P` doesn't exist in your DataGrid

Comment: Same problem described in your previous (identical) question: [Matching the values of Split string in if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735905/matching-the-values-of-split-string-in-if-condition). Here: `For x As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1`, you're looping through the DGV rows, checking the value of a Cell in a specific Column. At some point, that Cell value is **null**. You're then trying to split a **null** value. Of course you can't. The result is that no comparison will be performed or the comparison fails or you have an Exception.

Comment: You need to store the **previous value** and use this value when the **Cell content is null**. But you didn't say whether the (possibly) single valid value is always in the first row or (eventually) it can be found anywhere else or there might be more that one value to compare. Any possible solution depends on the missing informations.

Comment: i see the next value in per map is null that is why it doesnt compare ,is there a way to store the previous value If the next cell is null?

Comment: Okay the value for in the Source_Doc_No_P is always in the first row, that is why im splitting the value of BS091/BS092/BS093 to compare it to the values of Source_Doc_No

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim sdoc_map As String = DataGridView4.Rows(x).Cells("Source_Doc_No_P").Value.ToString
```

check Here.. I think just Confused With Cell Name . because Cells("Source_Doc_No_P") not Present here. Check the cell Name and then Proceed.

Comment: its all correct , if you see the screenshots I'm comparing Source_Doc_No_P to Source_Doc_No